# Navigating to blank PHP file returning 0 in browser

Tags: php, wordpress, admin-ajax

I'm running a WordPress install and was having issues with ajax-loads. Whenever I used the admin-ajax.php script, it wasn't returning anything so I decided to go to the source and see what the issue is.

It turns out that when I access the /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php file directly, it returns a `0` in the browser. **I emptied the file, saved it and then tried to access it directly and it still returned a `0`.** I know I'm on the correct server in the correct directory as I created test files in the same DIR.

Does anyone know why this would be happening? A blank php file (with 644 permissions, and the correct owner/group) returning a `0` when navigating to it directly?

**EDIT:** I have highlighted a sentence above as people are skipping over that part. I have emptied the file, it still returns `0`.

Answer (score 4):

That file can't be accessed directly, it must be accessed through an Ajax call and you must pass in some action parameters, as in the line 28 there is a check:

```
// Require an action parameter
if ( empty( $_REQUEST['action'] ) )
    die( '0' );
```

Try upgrading your installation to the latest version and check that you file size is larger than 3.75K ... If you have no cache installed than you shouldn't get a 0 from a empty php file. Do you use caching like cloudflare ?

Regarding the returned `0`, try the following code:

```
<?php
die('Hello');
```

it should return a simple Hello - on my side it works, at least :)

Comment: Thanks for your response however, as mentioned, I emptied the file and it was still returning a `0`

Comment: I've updated the answer, but the idea is: you shouldn't get a 0 from an empty php file, rather than that you should have received an empty html document. Try clear the browser cache and cookies (related with your website)

Comment: Yes I've done all that, hence the question - why would a blank PHP file return a `0`? Is this a server bug?

Comment: Check your plugins and see if you're using any caching system - if so temporary disable them. there is certainly a cache of your file somewhere. To be sure is not a browser cache try opening the same page on a chrome "Incognito window" which will start a new session without using the cache and cookies.

Comment: Put this content in your file and tell me what it returns:<?php
die('Hello');

Comment: Ok, there are no caching plugins etc. I have cleared my browser cache, started incognito in chrome, added `<?php die('Hello');` to the file and it is still returning `0` :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138067/discussion-between-codrut-tg-and-pavkr).